# Big blank space, wordpress

Tags: css

It is a big blank space at the bottom this website http://framgangspodden.se [1](http://framgangspodden.se)

I've been trying to change some CSS to figure that out but without any result.

Comment: The website is down.

Comment: I mistyped, I changed the post to the correct URL

Comment: `<div class="mkd-content" >` gets a `style="margin-bottom:580px;"`. It seems it's being applied by some javascript.

Comment: @Lars hmm, okey... do u know what to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Element `.mkd-content` has margin-bottom of 538px. It appears to be coming from javascript. You can override it by adding margin-bottom in css with !important

```
.mkd-content {
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 10px !important;
    background-color: #fff;
}
```

But, I would recommend you to find from where the margin gets added.

Comment: Ok, so what to do to fix this?

Comment: I added a solution, check the answer.